# What type of earth material is the author talking about?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, metaphors

"He (the giant king) would have liked to tame the very fire at the heart of the earth if he could in order to make the pillars for his throne room."

And what does "tame...the heart of the earth" mean?

I found that "to tame" means "to make a piece of land, a river etc able to be used ". But how the giant king wants to use the heart of the earth for the pillars? Is it a real magma? Or deeply buried stone? I don't get the meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the center of the earth - the earth’s core. Figuratively speaking, this person thinks he is so amazing that he would be worthy of using this material for his throne. As you have stated, this is obviously not literally possible, but it is just an expression of how this person is so brave and arrogant that he believes he is worthy of something impossible.